# Downloads folder grid view showing artifacts

Tags: macos, dock

When expanding the Downloads folder from the dock, in grid view, tooltips shown for long file name are leaving graphical artifacts after they disappear. There is a link below with a screen recording showing the issue.

If you have any hint on how to fix this, please leave a comment.

[Screen recording](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z0yiq9j3e40k5fy/dock-grid-view-artifacts.mov?dl=0)

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with a Spotlight importer specific to mobi files.  By dragging a 'folder' containing at least one mobi ebook file onto the right end of my dock I duplicated the behavior (OS X 10.10.5, Macbook 5,1).

Comment: I don't think it's related to the file type, I could reproduce this with a folder containing just pdf files. It just shows those artifacts whenever I expand the grid view of a dock folder.

Comment: I've only got two mdimpoters/qlgenerators installed and don't get anything but .mobi files to do this.